# React-testing-library render function throws syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to start using react-testing-library on my project.
Problem is, I can't setup everything properly.

Steps I made:

1. I installed @testing-library/react and jest-dom as documentation suggests.
2. I setup jest.config.js:

   ```
   module.exports = {
       setupFilesAfterEnv: [
           '@testing-library/react/cleanup-after-each',
       ],
   };
   ```
3. I wrote basic test:

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import App from '../App';
   import {render } from "@testing-library/react";

   it('renders without crashing', () => {
       const {asFragment} = render(<App/>);
       expect(asFragment).toMatchSnapshot();
   });
   ```

Error I get:

```
  4 |
  5 | it('renders without crashing', () => {
> 6 |     const {asFragment} = render(<App/>);
    |                                 ^
  7 |     expect(asFragment).toMatchSnapshot();
  8 | });
  9 |
```

My packages versions from package.json file:

```
"@testing-library/react": "^8.0.4",
"jest-dom": "^3.5.0",
"jest": "^24.8.0",
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
```

I've tried several things like cleanuping locally not from jest.config.js file to make it work, but nothing seems to work.

Edit: Project was created with CRA. Even though, I tried to configure babel and babel-jest myself as suggested but didn't work.

Comment: have you setup `babel` and `babel-jest`? you need them configured in order to transpile JSX code to JavaScript

Comment: Agree with @skyboyer, it looks like you don't have babel running in your tests. I suggest you try https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/ so you don't have to worry about all the configuration

Comment: I used CRA like @Gpx suggests

Comment: does it work to you?

Comment: No, it did not help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what was the problem here to be honest. I only know it happen when I was switching from enzyme to react-testing-library. 
Note: reverting to enzyme didn't work.

However, I can tell what worked. It was CRA-based project, which means I had all babel, webpack and jest configuration hidden from me. I decided to run `npm eject` only to fix configuration. Yet, after running this command tests started working again.